# Is the name of a two dimensional array address of the address of its first element in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

When implementing a two dimensional array like this:
    `int a[3][3];`
these hold: `A=&A[0]`, at the same time `A[0]=&A[0][0]`. So, `A=&(&A[0][0])`, what basically says that `A` is the address of the address of the first element of the array, which is not quite true. What is my mistake here? Does `A` really decay to a pointer to a pointer?

Comment: `A=&(&A[0][0])` is not a valid C expression. `&A[0][0]` is an address, and this adress has no address.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is that you have an incorrect understanding of the relationship between arrays and pointers. An array is not a pointer. It is an array. However, an array *is* implicitly convertible to a pointer to its own first element. So, while this expression does evaluate to true:

```
A == &A[0]
```

It is not correct to say that `A` *is* `&A[0]`. The conversion does not happen in all expressions. For example:

```
&A
```

This does not take the address of the address of the first element of `A` (that doesn't even make sense). It takes the actual address of `A`, who's type is `int[3][3]`. So the type of `&A` is `int(*)[3][3]`, read as "pointer to array of 3 arrays of 3 ints".

The primary difference between `&A` and `&A[0]` is that if you add 1 to `&A`, you will get an address that is `3 * 3 * sizeof(int)` bytes away, while if you add 1 to `&A[0]`, you will get a pointer that is only `3 * sizeof(int)` bytes away.

With all this in mind, you should be able to see where your mistake is. `A[0]` is *not* `&A[0][0]`, but it is implicitly convertible to it. However, like all conversions, this results in a temporary, which you cannot take the address of. So the expression `&(&A[0][0])` doesn't even make sense.

Comment: I don't think he's been "lied to". The title explicitly talks about the _name_ of the array.

Comment: In any case the semantics of arrays in C dictate that the array name is the address of the first element of the array, so I understand my own mistake now. With your first reaction I thought you meant that this was not even true. I was kinda baffled.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: tbh, I don't understand the significance of the word "name", here. The array name, like any other variable name, is how we communicate with the compiler about what object we are referring to (an array object, in this case). Anyway, I've removed assumptions about what the OP was told.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Array name decay .... arrays do not magically change to pointers, but the names of arrays may be treated as names of pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Because of reactions on my previous answer I did some research to learn more on whatever was wrong in my explanation.
Found a rather elaborate explanation of the topic here :

http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/10/21/are-pointers-and-arrays-equivalent-in-c

I'll try to summarize :

if you have following :

```
char array_place[100] = "don't panic";
char* ptr_place = "don't panic";
```

the way that this is represented in memory is entirely different.
whereas ptr_place is a real pointer, array_place is just a label.

```
char a = array_place[7];
char b = ptr_place[7];
```

**The semantics of arrays in C dictate that the array name is the address of the first element of the array, which is not the same as saying that it is a pointer.** Hence in the assignment to a, the 8th character of the array is taken by offsetting the value of array_place by 7, and moving the contents pointed to by the resulting address into the al register, and later into a.

The semantics of pointers are quite different. A pointer is just a regular variable that happens to hold the address of another variable inside. Therefore, to actually compute the offset of the 8th character of the string, the CPU will first copy the value of the pointer into a register and only then increment it. This takes another instruction [1].

This point is frequently ignored by programmers who don't actually hack on compilers. A variable in C is just a convenient, alphanumeric pseudonym of a memory location. Were we writing assembly code, we would just create a label in some memory location and then access this label instead of always hard-coding the memory value - and this is what the compiler does.

Well, actually the address is not hard-coded in an absolute way because of loading and relocation issues, but for the sake of this discussion we don't have to get into these details.

**A label is something the compiler assigns at compile time.** From here the great difference between arrays and pointers. **This also explains why sizeof(array_place) gives the full size of the array where as the size of a pointer will give the size of a pointer.**

I must say, I was not aware of these subtle differences myself, and I have been coding for quite a long time in C and C++ and with arrays too.

Nevertheless if the name of the array element is the address of the first element of the array. You can create a pointer and initialise it what that value

```
char* p = array_place
```

p will point to the memory location where the characters are.

to conclude :

There is one difference between an array name and a pointer that must be kept in mind. A pointer is a variable, so p=array_place and p++ are legal. But an array name is not a variable; constructions like array_place=p and array_place++ are illegal. That I did know ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately, answers which just link to a website are frowned upon. What if that website goes down?

Comment: It does give a good explanation though, I'll summarize if you let me.

Comment: I give you permission to summarize. (?)

Comment: pointer arithmetic is possible on `array_place` too, `*(array_place+3)` is perfectly valid, and equivalent to `array_place[3]`

Comment: voila, I think that should be it. thanks to those with constructive criticism.